# preg_replace escape slashes

Tags: php, regex

I get the *unknown modifier* error when the pattern contains slashes

code:

```
preg_replace('/$v/', $replacement, $string)
```

var $v, **sometimes** a directory path.

```
$v = folder/folder/file.ext
```

How do I deal with the $v in preg_replace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rolled back to my original answer since that's what turned out to work and dany accepted my answer.**

Escape it with `preg_quote()`, and use double quotes when placing it in a string:

```
$v = preg_quote($v, '/');
echo preg_replace("/$v/", $replacement, $string);
```

Then again if your `$v` doesn't have any regex metacharacters, and you just want to do an exact match, use `str_replace()` instead:

```
echo str_replace($v, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't think this is what I want. Adding slashes changes the regex pattern and does not replace it as a result. Also the variable does contain regex characters

Comment: @dany: OK, so all you want is to escape the `/` characters, am I correct?

Comment: @BoltClock: I just want to replace the pattern that contains slashes-with a value. ex. from "folder/folder/folder/file" to "foo"

Comment: That's what preg_quote is made for ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: My mistake, your first answer was the solution. My code was faulty. sorry :)

Comment: @dany: Bah, shall I roll it back? But mario's answer has it already.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think so. Also insert an edit note for the second one. Again, Im sorry.

Answer (score 3):

None of the existing answers is absolutely right.

The correct way to escape PREG symbols with `preg_replace()` is the following:

```
$delim = '~';
$search = preg_quote('folder/folder/file.ext', $delim);
$replace = addcslashes($replace, '\\$');
//$replace = preg_quote($replace); // don't use $delim here!

$string = preg_replace($delim . $search . $delim, $replace, $string);
```

`$replace` also needs to be escaped, otherwise `$0` would return the matched string for example.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative!

Comment: I don't think `preg_quote` is universally suitable for escaping the replacement string. A single `.` will become `\.` and the preg_replace call will not undo the escaping. - There needs to be an escaping function specifically for the `$0` and `\\1` cases.

Comment: @mario: Didn't though of that... I guess that `addcslashes($replace, '\\$')` would be a good solution then.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to escape strings for use in regular expressions is [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
$v = preg_quote($v, '/');
preg_replace('/$v/', $replacement, $string)
```

It takes care that not only the delimiter `/` gets escaped, but also all other regex meta characters like dots or braces or other escape sequences.